# Change language in multilingual website with next.js

Tags: next.js, localization, url-routing

I've recently started with Next.js and I'm busy creating my first website, which of course I would like to have multilingual.

I've followed official documentation => https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization

I've created middleware like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { match } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher'
import Negotiator from 'negotiator'
 

let headers = { 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5' }
let languages = new Negotiator({ headers }).languages()
let locales = ['en', 'nl', 'fr']
let defaultLocale = 'nl'
 

// Get the preferred locale, similar to above or using a library
function getLocale(request: any): string { 
    return match(languages, locales, defaultLocale) // -> 'en-US'
 }
 
export default function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
  console.log("Middleware is executed");

  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname
  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = locales.every(
    (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
  )
 
  // Redirect if there is no locale
  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = getLocale(request);
    console.log(locale);
    console.log(request);
    // e.g. incoming request is /products
    // The new URL is now /en-US/products
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(`/${locale}/${pathname}`, request.url)
    )
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip all internal paths (_next)
    '/((?!_next).*)',
    // Optional: only run on root (/) URL
    // '/'
  ],
}
```

And the structure looks like this

[image]

And I have a language switcher:

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default function LanguageSwitcher() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li><Link href="/" locale="en">EN</Link></li>
        <li><Link href="/" locale="nl">NL</Link></li>
        <li><Link href="/" locale="fr">FR</Link></li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
```

I have several problems:

1. The language switcher does not work, I cannot switch the languages doing like that.
2. If I put for example site.com/de/contact then it will go to site.com/nl/de/contact. For unknown languages he will add default language :(
3. I don't know exactly how to do it that the default language keeps normal routing site.com / site.com/contact / etc

Can anyone advise?

I've checked multiple blogs, but first of all they talk about page routing (the older system), + they include some other packages, which I don't really need for simplicity.
Although I've tried those libraries, but couldn't make the work correctly anyways.

Answer (score 0):

On your middleware function, you have a line that checks if the pathname is missing like this:

```js
const pathnameIsMissingLocale = locales.every(
  (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
)
```

But by doing this you are asking it to check if the pathname has EVERY locales, and you should be looking for .some() because if it matches one of the locales, it is enough to know that it is correct.

So change it to be:

```js
const pathnameIsMissingLocale = locales.some(
  (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
)
```

This should handle the link not redirecting to the right place. Now about leaving the default lang, change middleware to contain this:

```js
//...
const url = req.nextUrl.clone()
const pathnameIsMissingLocale = locales.some(
  (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
)
const isDefaultLocale = !pathNameIsMissingLocale || pathname.startsWith(`/${defaultLocale}/`)

if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = getLocale(request);
    
    locale === defaultLocale 
      ? url.pathname = `/${pathname}`
      : url.pathname = `/${locale}/${pathname}`
    
    return NextResponse.redirect(url)
}
if(isDefaultLocale) {
  url.pathname = `/${pathname}`
  return NextResponse.redirect(url)
}
//...
```

This change should check if the link is defaultLocale and change the pathname accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, but this code generates me a link like this:
http://localhost:3000/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/ and it keeps just growing by it self =)